# Determine when windows form finished loading (including GUI creation)

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, forms, loading

my application consists of 2 forms. one is the startup one and tiny.. the other one is packed with components.

when the users presses a button on the startup form, the other one should be shown of course. this works with a little problem. because there is a big datagridview on the 2nd form and more components windows takes it time to create the Usercontrols and during this time the form is not usable, not even clickable or properly designed.

so my question is, if there is any event of the form which tells me, when the form is properly loaded.. including all GUI measures?!

thanks :)

Comment: The term "loading" is very imprecise.  Start with the Shown event first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But you can, first, display message "loading" and call me.show - this will ensure your form shows and displays useful information. Once finish loading, remove the message.

Another option is to load on background worker thread. This way form will be responsive while you loading.

Comment: Since the background thread won't have a message queue, I think this means load the data on a background thread and when it's ready load it into the form, which is loaded on the UI thread, of course.

Comment: thank you.. in first place i will skip the background worker and hide the controls as long as they are loading :)